# lightning-input type="toggle" change label font

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

Is it possible to do it?

```
<lightning-input
          class="cxd-toggle__label-medium"
          type="toggle"
          label="Block list"
          checked={relaxedChecked}
          disabled={relaxedDisabled}
          onchange={unlockCheckboxesRelaxed}
        ></lightning-input>
```

css

```
        .cxd-toggle__label-medium {
  font-size: 14px;}
```

wasn't able to find some webhooks

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use styling hooks to customize the styles of the [lightning-input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/documentation) component, rather than overriding the `slds-form-element__label` class.

[Styling hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/) are **CSS** custom properties that let you change the appearance of base components without affecting their functionality or behaviour.

You can use the `:host` selector to apply the styling hooks to your component.

For example, to change the font size of the label, you can use the `--lwc-formLabelFontSize` styling hook:

```
:host {
--lwc-formLabelFontSize: 14px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it really doesn't work. For now style is kinda :host .cxd-toggle__label-medium {
  --slds-form-element__label-font-size: 16px;
  }

Comment: I have edited my answer please check.

Comment: It works but there is need to center it vertically now. Where can i find the whole --lwc hooks list for form elements?